# Wiring multiple I2C sensors to Raspberry Pi using breadboard or wiring

Tags: i2c, wiring

I am new in prototyping with Raspberry Pi. I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B. For a project I want to connect 3 I2C sensors to it (AS7262,BME688 and AS7263. They connect to the same pinns (pins 1, 3, 5, 6, 9). I have read around that that is possible by wiring them in parallel. How do I practically do it? I cannot figure out (beginner at that too) how to wire them on a breadborad or by using wires. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of connection should do the trick. Right?[image]

Comment: That looks fine.  You can daisy chain the I2C signals (as you have shown in your diagram).  Conceptually all the SDA are one point as are all the SCL signals.  So you could use star wiring instead or a combination of both, whatever is most convenienr to wire.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. As I said., I am completely new to circuits. What is a star wiring and how do I translate it terms of cables/connections on my breadboard? Do you have any diagram, photo?

Comment: Star wiring at its simplest is an individual wire from each device SDA/SCL to the Pi SDA/SCL.